# Auto logon to internet provider

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet-connection, captive-portal

We use a wireless internet access.  The wireless is secured and to get an IP address, when you provide the right key.  That is currently working properly, however, the first time we access the internet, a browser page appears and we have to enter a password.  We have access to the internet after that for a period of time.  How can the password step be automated?

Comment: What is the purpose of the browser page? The best solution is probably just to achieve that objective, whatever it is, some other way.

Comment: It is done by the internet provider.  I have no control of it.

Comment: Right, but what is its purpose? You don't need control of it. You can bypass it without control, but how you do it depends on what its purpose is -- since you need to do whatever its purpose was some other way.

Comment: If you will make the password step automated, wouldn't that be a security risk, in some sense? Suppose a someone had physical access to your computer, he can waste your surfing time by logging in without worrying what the password is. The countdown doesn't start until you provide the credentials anyway.

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. According to the [FAQ#dontask], questions should be reasonably scoped. This will get you more precise answers and makes it easier for others to find the topics later on. I've edited your post to remove additional questions – feel free to ask them as separate posts, and link back to this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your having to log into a browser based system you can use [lastpass](https://lastpass.com/), which works on all major browsers, mobile devices.  After you've entered your username & password once, lastpass will automatically log into the site for you:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using your own wireless network than you can secure it yourself when you configure your router. You'll only have to type in a password once for every device you connect with.

What is the browser page that shows up periodically when you're browsing? If you take a screenshot and edit it into your post I might be able to help you more. My guess is that you have some setting turned on in your router settings. If you can't access your router (don't know the username/password) then you can physically reset it. Usually there is a button you hold down for 10 seconds, and it might be indented so use a pen.